# Cannot run parcel command

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, parceljs

I am trying to run parcel. I keep getting the following errors.

npm run start

> frontend@1.0.0 start /Users/laurasaydeh/Desktop/dragonstack/frontend
>   parcel index.html

sh: parcel: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 start: `parcel index.html`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Here is my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

I have tried cleaning the cache, re-installing npm after deleting node modules.
I have also tried changing the start command to parcel build index.js.

I have no clue why this is not working

UPDATE: I believe parcel is not installing at all. [Parcel not being intalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290768/parcel-not-being-intalled)

Comment: parcel is not a dependency of your project.

Comment: Oh thank you! I see now. I have it installed globally, but I am trying to use the start script. I will test it out later tonight and see if it works.

Comment: I believe this is unrelated. It doesn't work globally either. I made a new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290768/parcel-not-being-intalled