# Parcel not being intalled

Tags: node.js, npm, parceljs

I am trying to add parcel bundler to my machine.

Here is the list of commands that I have tried in order.

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm@latest -g
npm install -g parcel-bundler
```

Parcel then appears to have installed correctly, but it does not.

RELATED QUESTION: [Cannot run parcel command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272654/cannot-run-parcel-command)

When I try and run

```
parcel --version
```

I get this

```
bash: parcel: command not found
```

Here are all the versions I am running on my machine

**parcel-bundler version 1.12.3**

**npm version 6.4.1**

**node version v10.11.0 updated to v11.12.0 which also does not work**

Comment: It's just the `PATH` bash variable doesn't include you global `node_modules/.bin` folder

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
npm parcel --version
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck